# Rotation and Momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I understand that according to one of Euler's theorems, any solid object's 3D rotational orientation can be represented by a single 3D vector and an amount, i.e. a 4D vector.

However, is it correct to extend this to momentum?  i.e. is it correct that a solid object's rotational momentum can be expressed by a vector?  Or are there more complicated factors at play (e.g. wobble, etc.)

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28955/moment-of-inertia-of-a-football-and-its-angular-momentum  One of the features that I found confusing regarding angular momentum is that its calculation is dependent on the arbitrary choice of axis. A mass moving in a straight line has an angular momentum relative to an arbitrary point off that line.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can. Angular momentum (the rotational analog to linear momentum) can be expressed as an *axial* vector (sometimes called [pseudovector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector)), which means a quantity that is similar to a regular vector, except for the fact that it changes sign under improper rotations (such as reflections). I suppose you're refering by "wobble" to [nutation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation), i. e., a small oscillation on the axis of rotation of a spinning object, such as a top.
This is related to the presence of an [external torque](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque), which produces an angular acceleration, then a change on angular momentum:

$$\tau=\frac{dL}{dt}$$

For a more detailed explanation of the mechanism behind the nutation effect, see the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53153/what-causes-precession-or-nutation-in-a-spinning-object).